# Install emacs customized way

Tags: linux, centos, emacs, fedora

I am using fedora 22/centos 7 (x86_64) on my Acer laptop.  I was trying to install Emacs GNU editor.

```
dnf -y install emacs
```

When I am installing Emacs GNU editor it installs Emacs and Emacs client both.  Removing Emacs-client removes Emacs also. Is there any way so that I can install Emacs without Emacs client getting installed?

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?  Emacsclient is a tiny little binary thing that relies upon Emacs.  The two executables (i.e., emacs and emacsclient) are generally treated as part of Emacs, not separate animals.  You are essentially asking how to cut out a component that is part of a standard Emacs installation.

Answer (score 1):

```
rpm -e --nodeps emacsclient
```

this'll probably break emacs, as @lawlist mentioned.